# SQL Query Grabbing data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

My code right now is this

```
$extract = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM items");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($extract);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($extract)) {
    $id = $row['i_id'];
    $iname = $row['i_name'];    
    echo "<tr><td><a href='capture.php?item_id=$id'>$iname</a></td><td>Incomplete</td></tr>";
}
```

What i want to do is run a check to see if the item has already been completed.
I have a separate table that contains the information, for instance say that Item 1 has been completed then I would like to be able to change my echo to something like:

```
 echo "<tr><td>$iname</td><td>Complete!</td></tr>";
```

**How would I accomplish this? Would I need to use some form of a join statement?**

I want to be able to display all the items in the table but not duplicate them i initially thought that an if statement on the echo to see if item complete then do this else do that

Here are the two tables

```
Items                      item_collection
------                     ---------------
i_id                       i_id
i_name                     complete
                           caption
                           image
                           c_id
                           g_id
```

Comment: Please include your database structure.

Comment: can you post table structure for two tables?

Comment: yeah sorry about that let me do that real quick

Comment: @JoshC., will there be multiple rows in item_collection table for given item?

Comment: yes each group (g_id) will have a information for a single item. Well can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join condition like this (assuming complete is a varchar field)

```
SELECT a.i_id, a.i_name,
CASE WHEN i_status = '1' THEN 'Complete!' ELSE 'Incomplete' END AS complete_status
FROM items a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_collection b ON a.i_id = b.i_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
case 
  when ic.complete = 1 then 'Complete'   
  else 'Incomplete'
end as item_status
from items i
left join item_collection ic on i.i_id = ic.i_id
where i.i_name = 'your_item_name'
```

Assuming that ic.complete = 1 when item is complete.

Comment: would this display all the items? because i initially thought that an if statement on the echo to see if item complete then do this else do that

Comment: @JoshC. this will return the status for a specific item `where i.i_name = your_item_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id not in (SELECT Id FROM table2)